# Accessing site on nginx by https by default

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, nginx, https

I have website on nginx server! I want to make accessing the site by https by default(on specified port, I wrote in below)! I mean, when I write in browser - `mysite.net:90`, or `www.mysite.net:90`, it will go on https, instead of http! I've already tried to redirect requests with "rewrite" in server block, and "return", but it doesn't work.

This is how my server block looks now:

```
 server {

         listen 90;  
         listen 9090 ssl;

         server_name example.com;

         ssl on;
         ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;


         root /var/www/path;

         fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
         fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https; 
         ......

     }
```

Comment: Have you tried port 443? That's the default port for HTTPS. Or do you require specifically to run under port 9090?

Comment: Yes! But it still doesn't accesing the site by https protocol by default!

Comment: So when you access `https://www.example.com` it does work under port 443 but you would like that when accessing through HTTP only `http://www.example.com` to be redirected to HTTPS by default is that correct? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: No, a bit different! The case is next:
I write in browser example.com, or www.example.com, or http://example.com or even http://www.example.com, and I want to access the site by https, without typing https before my domain name! I explain it correct? By the way, then I access site by https://example.com:9090, as it wrote in server block, it works! But I want to redirect http to https, or how it call :0

Answer (score 0):

You may find this forum post useful:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/http-https-redirect-positive-ssl-on-nginx

Basically you need to create a redirection from your HTTP instance where all requests are automatically redirected to HTTPS.

Like this:

```nginx
server {
    listen      90;  
    server_name example.com;
    # Redirect all requests to https
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen              9090 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    root                /var/www/path;

    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https; 

}
```

Try that and see if that works for you.
But basically you for the first instance, you are simply creating a redirection and all the real configuration will be on the second one.

Comment: Oh sir, I was tried something like this, already! I this I just missing something in configuration! Btw, "return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;" - this section will return site in https, or obligatory need to write for, example - example.com/users, and only the it will redirects me to https://example.com/users/ ?

Comment: This will be a catch-all meaning anything on the website will be automatically rewritten to HTTPS, all paths and subpaths, etc.